# Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, exchangewebservices

I was trying to follow the steps from this [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903761(v=exchg.150).aspx) tutorial to authenticate my app by oAuth and use the retrieved token for EWS managed API.

Here is the final code:

```
static void Run()
        {
            string authority = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["authority"];
            string clientID = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["clientID"];
            Uri clientAppUri = new Uri(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["clientAppUri"]);
            string serverName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["serverName"];

            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);


            string errorMessage = null;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying to acquire token");
                authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(serverName, clientID, clientAppUri, PromptBehavior.Auto);
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    errorMessage += "\nInnerException : " + ex.InnerException.Message;
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed: {0}" + errorMessage);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nMaking the protocol call\n");
            ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
            exchangeService.Url = new Uri(serverName + "ews/exchange.asmx");
            exchangeService.TraceEnabled = true;
            exchangeService.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
            exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
            //exchangeService.TraceListener = new TraceListener();
            var res = exchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, new FolderView(10));
        }
```

and here is the configuration file:

```
    <add key="authority" value="https://login.windows.net/???.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="clientId" value="???" />
    <add key="clientAppUri" value="https://localhost/8a4abb13c70dab64a18ae81089bc2cff"/>
    <add key="serverName" value="https://outlook.office365.com/" />
```

Here is the error message:

```
The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

and here is trace of ExchangeService:

```
<Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="12" Time="2015-08-13 13:56:24Z">
POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0847.030
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSIsImtpZCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSJ9.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.tZAyNFquVvyg46lsN79bmpdHhVEPwCIbBXfgsQ3kCzXgmf0LmX3s0A6SV7eSfEKef_-U78HBViAIaUexWeKAV0SKzJZUiQJ0dpDossYt6CfBAlFn4J6_5oZ_jygeNH3xeiCgU4tQrlz5t8iMOeSmBjwIsa2K-Sizd_zC8m3wptg6HI2ubdFJd0VXYqb7WFW_Sb-7wmOZqp8Lybpf3W6qRO14FRpm1f0RGec7kx4jd0EobPUaYWnQaet2I8P-5tuq6fmkJx78mQLGCrkZMcSJVakWVgepgO3LrEvKRKLuzJ9p5fiRiEVGNAzHUubrIjCVcXuquYaPdF16dK3gUT3Uiw


</Trace>
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="12" Time="2015-08-13 13:56:24Z" Version="15.00.0847.030">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:FindFolder Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:FolderShape>
          <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
        </m:FolderShape>
        <m:IndexedPageFolderView MaxEntriesReturned="10" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
        <m:ParentFolderIds>
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="root" />
        </m:ParentFolderIds>
      </m:FindFolder>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
<Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="12" Time="2015-08-13 13:56:26Z">
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
request-id: ea025c98-9e74-4799-8ac2-77251f641912
X-CalculatedBETarget: HE1PR09MB0330.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 401
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: ClientId=4HGSRI510SWOAIFT0U31G; expires=Fri, 12-Aug-2016 13:57:17 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly,exchangecookie=86f12da3fb89403bb91c5fe8b525f43d; expires=Sat, 13-Aug-2016 13:57:18 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly,ClientId=4HGSRI510SWOAIFT0U31G; expires=Fri, 12-Aug-2016 13:57:17 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
x-ms-diagnostics: 2000001;reason="No applicable user context claims found.";error_category="invalid_token"
X-DiagInfo: HE1PR09MB0330
X-BEServer: HE1PR09MB0330
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: DB5PR09CA0061
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oautA first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
h2/authorize", error="invalid_token",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm=""
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 13:57:17 GMT


</Trace>
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Hamid I need to implement oauth for EWS application but not being able to figure out where to get the parameters for my app like authority/clientId/clientAppUri and serverName. I have registered my app on azure portal (portal.azure.com) but not able to see the info like app uri etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token has too many scopes in it (i.e. the `scp` claim). That value should only be `full_access_as_user`. In the Azure Management Portal, the only Office 365 Exchange Online permission you should have is "Access mailboxes as the signed-in user via Exchange Web Services".

Comment: I ran into another problem. It can only be logged in by the user who registered the app in Azure AD. for ordinary users, give me 401 error. any idea?

Comment: Alright, I used "https://login.windows.net/common" for authority and now I am able to login with other accounts as well.