# How to get the oauth parameters for EWS app

Tags: c#, oauth, exchangewebservices

I have an EWS application for which I am supposed to implement oauth for accessing EWS managed APIs. I am trying to follow the code posted here: [Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31990348/2858235) but not being able to figure out how to get the parameters like authority/clientId/clientAppUri and serverName. I have registered my app on azure portal but do not see any such info related to my app.
Also, I am not able to see any permission saying "Access mailboxes as the signed-in user via Exchange Web Services" on azure management portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question in that SO post references an [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903761(v=exchg.150).aspx) article which has a [section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903761(v=exchg.150).aspx#Anchor_1) that explains what those values should be:

> The Azure AD Authentication Library for .NET simplifies getting an
>   authentication token from Azure Active Directory so that you can use
>   the token in your application. You need to provide four pieces of
>   information to get the token:
>
> 1. The URI of the token server. The token server is the authority that authenticates the user and returns a token that your application
>      can use to access EWS.
> 2. The application client ID created when you registered your application with Azure Active Directory.
> 3. The application client URI created when you registered your application with Azure Active Directory.
> 4. The URI of the EWS server and the URI of the EWS endpoint. For Exchange as part of Office 365, this will be https:///ews/exchange.asmx.
>
> The following code shows how to use the Azure AD Authentication
>   Library to get an authentication token. It assumes that the
>   information required to make the authentication request is stored in
>   the application's App.config file

```
string authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authority"];
string clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientID"];
Uri clientAppUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientAppUri"];
string serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverName"];

AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(serverName, clientId, clientAppUri);
```

Comment: I tried following the msdn article but still not able to figure out the authority url, so in my case I now know that the servername is https://outlook.office365.com/ since thats the url returned as a part of autodiscovery of the user. But I am still not sure about rest, for authority, should I go ahead and use the same as mentioned in the article : http://login.windows.net/<devAccountName>.onmicrosoft.com where devaccountname would be the email address of the user?

Comment: and for client app uri I think I need to use the same url which I entered while registering my app on azure. I know the client id for sure now :)

Comment: The Authority key should have it's value set to the Azure domain (some_domain.onmicrosoft.com) of your organization account. 
So for example, if the organizational account is bob@contoso.onmicrosoft.com. Then, the authority is http://login.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: In that case, I am wondering which parameter will contain the user account specific information to authenticate the user?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm only familiar with authenticating the client. Regardless, you should be asking that in a separate SO question.

Comment: @tavier I think my answer satisfies your original question, so please consider to mark it as the answer.