# C# app authenticate EWS using OAuth throwing error AADSTS65005: Invalid resource

Tags: c#, oauth, exchangewebservices

C# test application to authenticate EWS using OAuth is throwing the following error

Error Details:
*AADSTS65005: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID:xxxxxxxxx*

We have followed the steps provided in the link to register the application
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

and trying to test the code from [Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990348/authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth)

Please help to know why this code is throwing an error AADSTS65005: Invalid resource.
also want to know where to grant full_access_as_user for this application that I registered in the https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.

Comment: The error is telling you that in the application registration you have created it doesn't list the resource eg https://outlook.office365.com your trying to access. So that tells you there is problem with the Application registration. Maybe try testing oAuth using the EWSEditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Glen. I checked EWSEditor. I could successfully login using Oauth using default values provided in the application for the RedirectURL and  Client app id. However when i provide the Client app id from the registration i have done in the portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) is not working and throws the same error as before "AADSTS65005: Invalid resource."

Comment: Thanks Glen. I checked EWSEditor. I could successfully login using Oauth using default values provided in the application for the RedirectURL and  Client app id. But, when i provide my app Client app id from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com it is not working & throws error "AADSTS65005: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration." I think i am missing something in registration & permissions, any pointers on how to register the application & required permissions to be granted will help.

Comment: With EWS you only have one permission that will work maybe post a screen shot of your registration.